# What software can I use to Edit PDF online?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf-editor

I have already built a database and using php I can edit,delete etc... from the database.
I need an app which I can integrate in my app to edit pdf.
I should be in such a way that when I click on the name on the database the file will be opened using the PDF editor automatically such that the user can edit the PDF ( The php and mysql part is okay)(PDF is already on server)
Can you help by suggestion what PDF editor can I use and how to use it or even alternatives to what I want
Also guide me how to integrate and use the app
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this site](https://www.pdfescape.com).

it's not fully free but have these features for **free members**:

1. Edit PDF Files
2. Annotate PDF Documents
3. Fill Out PDF Forms
4. Create New (Basic) PDF Forms
5. Password Protect PDF Files
6. Share Documents Online
7. View PDF Files

Answer (score 0):

I always use https://smallpdf.com/ to edit and convert PDFs. I'm not sure whether you can integrate it or not, but this may be the best online editor.